# Cannot Reinstall Visual Studio Code After New PC Move

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, visual-studio-code

let me outline that there are 2 PCs in this problem; 1 old pc and 1 new pc. The old PC had visual studio code installed on a secondary drive.

Later, I moved the main drive to the 1 new pc. I then activated windows 10 again on the new pc. I also made sure that the visual studio code folder in %appdata%/user is deleted, etc (on the main drive). I was unable to uninstall visual studio code b/c it is no longer available from the secondary drive which failed in the 1 old pc.

I'm having a hard time installing visual studio code again and get: "The drive or UNC share you selected does not exist or is not accessible. Please select another"

I also checked the storage settings for “change where new content is saved”, and all drives are good.

What steps should I do? I tried deleting files and folders and .vscode in the main drive also...

Comment: Maybe a permission issue, Do you have rights the rights to that folder?

Comment: Please provide the installation logs

Comment: @Ramhound how do I get the installation logs? Atm I can't even get past the first 2 menu prompts of the install wizard.

Comment: @Roys - When I performed a Google search on the subject, it appears, that [%AppData%\Code\logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373762/where-are-visual-studio-code-log-files) might be the directory.  However, that might not be the installation logs, so I will try to figure it out myself.  Are you using the User Installer or System Installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, is delete all Visual Studio Code folders, as if it were a new fresh install.

- VSCode **extensions** are located in `%userprofile%/.vscode`.

  *If you have a list of your extensions and don't mind re-downloading those, you can delete that folder.*
- VSCode **user and configuration files** are located in `%appdata%\Roaming\Code\User`.

  *I really recommend you to **save that folder or make a backup somewhere**. There is all your VSCode settings. After that, you can delete that folder.*
- VSCode **excecutables and program files** are located in `%localappdata%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`.

  *There are no problem deleting that folder, your settings are backed up anyway. This can solve some excecutable/installer conflicts tho.*

---

If that doesn't work, it's pretty sure the "Uninstaller" registered on Windows is inaccessible. You can remove the program in Control Panel list manually using software like CCleaner or [Bulk Crap Uninstaller](https://www.bcuninstaller.com/) (I recommend this one).

**OR**, deleting this key in registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{771FD6B0-FA20-440A-A002-3B3BAC16DC50}_is1
```

That last solution was proposed in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109518#issuecomment-717965782) on VSCode repo on GitHub: