# Cannot reinstall Git after new PC move

Tags: windows, windows-10, git, git-bash

This is similar to my previous question [Cannot Reinstall VS Code After New PC Move](https://superuser.com/questions/1674185/cannot-reinstall-visual-studio-code-after-new-pc-move)

I tried to uninstall Git using Program and Features but cannot, since the uninstall file is not located on this drive anymore.

This time I also tried going to the Registry Editor and delete the Git folders from HKEY_CURRENT_USER and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, but still get :
"The drive or UNC share you selected does not exist or is not accessible." when trying to install Git.

What else should I do or try?

EDIT:
I added an image of my registry editor:
[registry editor and Git Setup Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf4Mo.png)

Local machine registry dir: [local_machine_regedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy287.png)

Comment: Did you delete the Git entry from windows Uninstaller registry path?

Comment: @Robert I think so, what is the full path in Regedit?

Comment: Look at the answer of the question you have linked. The only difference is that GIT is installed for all users hence it can be found in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Comment: @Robert yea i deleted that then, but still the same issue; I'm not sure if maybe minGW, iirc, could be an issue too... but I'm willing to try anything atm, I need git-bash again

Comment: I will go back to my previous suggestion of providing the installation logs of the GIt installer.  Your screenshot is of `HKEY_LOCAL_USER` not `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Have you deleted the Git folders within the various subdirectories within %AppData%?

Comment: @Ramhound ah ok, I'll delete any Git related folders in Roaming and Local, idk if other Git-like software might cause problem too like Gitkraken so I'll delete those too and try again

Comment: Okay, I tried what you said, I get the same message. I also tried CCleaner this time to check registry files and restarted. Still, no luck installing Git-2.33.0.2-64-bit, I get the same error message; this seems more difficult than reinstalling VS Code... What else can I try?